# How to minimize requested image using jquery cropit plugin?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, image

My code is cropping an image but cropped image is very large. I'm using the [Cropit jQuery plugin](http://scottcheng.github.io/cropit/).

My View has an div mask on the image. When the form post, the hidden input has cropped image through the following script.

```
<div class="image-editor" style="margin-left:120px; margin-bottom:25px; margin-top:25px;">
    <input id="fileinput" type="file" name="filex" class="cropit-image-input">
    <div class="cropit-image-preview" style="background-image:url()"></div>
    <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
    <input type="hidden" name="image-data" value="" class="hidden-image-data" />
    <button type="submit" class="export">Crop</button>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $('.image-editor').cropit({});
        $('.export').click(function () {
            var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
            $('.hidden-image-data').val(imageData);
        });
     });
</script>
```

In my Controller Create function gets cropped image via Request and write to file but the new file is too large. For example, input file is 50kb and cropped output file is 600kb. Normally the cropped image must be smaller than input image. How to fix the problem?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var dataurl = Request["image-data"];
    var data = dataurl.Substring(dataurl.IndexOf(",") + 1);
    var newfile = Convert.FromBase64String(data);

    var layoutfilename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_imgage.jpg";
    var dataFile = Server.MapPath(@"~/Img/" + layoutfilename);
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(dataFile, newfile);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at Cropit's source code, here's the relevant bit of code to the output data size:

```
Cropit.prototype.getCroppedImageData = function(exportOptions) {
var canvas, canvasContext, croppedSize, exportDefaults, exportZoom;
if (!this.imageSrc) {
     return null;
}
     exportDefaults = {
     type: "image/png",
     quality: .75,
     originalSize: false,
     fillBg: "#fff"
};
exportOptions = $.extend({}, exportDefaults, exportOptions);
```

This is the beginning of the function eventually called by `cropit('export')`.

What's happened here is your input data's compression yields a smaller input than what a quality (7, 8, not sure here) PNG image would output.

You can specify options in the `cropit()` call - from the plugin's documentation:

```
$imageCropper.cropit('export', {
  type: 'image/jpeg',
  quality: .9,
  originalSize: true
});
```

Comment: edited the type is jpg, quality is 0.5 and originalsize: true but did not work it takes notice 10 kb smaller.

Comment: The output data size is solely dependent upon the options you pass to `cropit`. I've personally never used cropit, so I'm unable to provide you with an exact solution, but this should get you in the right direction.

Comment: Do you know any cropper facebook style?

Comment: The output image is resampled so it can be larger than the original image (e.g. if the input image is highly compressed). @jdphenix has provided the right track, use jpeg type and a small `quality` value should do it. Setting `originalSize` to false (which is default) can also help reduce the output file size.

Comment: None of work. Everytime outputting larger image. Are there any way without resampled? At the same time, when the input file is 1mb and larger images, occured the error that "System.Web.HttpException:reached the largest request length".

Comment: I'm sorry guys. In the following setting is working. The settings compressing imgage 600kb to 25kb. Before my question, may be an error in my IIS server.
             `exportDefaults = {
                type: "image/jpeg",
                quality: .55,
                originalSize: false,
                fillBg: "#fff"
            };`

Comment: @a_TES Feel free to edit my answer with the details of the error in your server configuration that caused your problem - I'm genuinely curious myself.

Comment: I applied your first answer to cropit.js and compiled the project on Visual Studio. Even though I refreshed the browser, I still kept getting the same error like I never saved the changes. When I added restarting the browser to my next tries, I saw that your answer worked. Thanks @jdphenix